# continually add values in javascript with while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, root

I'm a newbie to Javascript so please bear with me for this basic question,

I'm trying to get my function to add all the individual digits in a string together, and then keep doing this until I'm left with a single digit!

```
3253611569939992595156

113 // result of the above digits all added together

5 //result of 1+1+3
```

I've created a while loop, but it only adds the numbers together once, it dosn't repeat until a single digit and I can't work out why!

```js
function rootFunc(n) {
  var splite = n.toString().split('').map(x => Number(x)); //converts the number to a string, splits it and then converts the values back to a number

  while (splite.length > 1) {
    splite = splite.reduce(getSum);
  }

  return splite;
}

console.log(rootFunc(325361156993999259515));

function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}
```

Comment: At a first glance I'm going to say that after you call your reduce fn and modify `splite`, it becomes a single value, so you won't be looping again.   I recommend going over the [docs for reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 2):

You're reducing properly, but what you're not doing is re-splitting. Try breaking this out into separate functions:

```
function digits(n) {
  return n.toString().split('').map(x =>Number(x));
}
```

Then split each time:

```
function rootFunc(n) {
  var d = digits(n);
  while (d.length > 1) {
    d = digits(d.reduce(getSum));
  }

  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you return the result after the first splice. You need to have a recursive function. To do this, you can put this before the return :

```
  if(splite > 9) splite = rootFunc(splite);
```

This way, you check if the result is greater than 10, if not you do the function with the  remaining digits

Answer (score 1):

I was looking this over in jsfiddle, and your number isn't being passed to exact precision, so just console logging n as soon as you call rootFunc, you've already lost data. Otherwise, to fix your loop, you need to remap splite to a string before the end of your codeblock since your while statement is checking .length, which needs to be called on a string. Put this piece of code at the end of the block:
 `splite = splite.toString().split('').map(x =>Number(x));`

Comment: Hi Bezlonr, thank you for posting your first answer on StackOverflow! To help increase the readability of your answer, please the code snippets into code blocks and object/method/variable names. You can use the editor's code block feature or qwrap the word in backquotes (top left key on PC keyboard). For example `this`